# Reverse dictionary mapping incorrectly

Tags: python, dictionary, key-value

I have a `ingredient_dict` dictionary I'm trying to apply in reverse to the `Ingredients` column wherever values in the column appear as values in the key-value pairs.

```
ingredient_dict = {
                    'Aardappelen': ('Dunne frieten', 'Half kruimige aardappelen', 'Voorgekookte halve kriel met schil',
                                    'Kruimige aardappelen', 'Roodschillige aardappelen', 'Opperdoezer Ronde aardappelen'),
                    'Kipgehakt': ('Gemengd gekruid gehakt', 'Kipgehakt met Mexicaanse kruiden', 'Half-om-halfgehakt met Italiaanse kruiden',
                                  'Kipgehakt met tuinkruiden'),
                    'Ui': ("Rode ui"),
                    'Kipfilet': ('Kipfilet met tuinkruiden en knoflook'),
                    'Kipworst': ('Gekruide kipworst'),
                    'Kipshoarma': ('Kalkoenshoarma')
                    }

reverse_label_ing = {x:k for k,v in ingredient_dict.items() for x in v}
# df_check["Ingredients"].replace(reverse_label_ing, inplace=True)
```

When I show the `reverse_label_ing` result I see "Aardappelen" for example was reversed correctly but I get issues with `Rode ui` and `Gekruide kipworst` and `Kalkoenshoarma` and I'm not sure why. Anyone know why the individual characters of "Rode ui" for instance are showing up as individual keys?:

```
reverse_label_ing

{'Dunne frieten': 'Aardappelen',
 'Half kruimige aardappelen': 'Aardappelen',
 'Voorgekookte halve kriel met schil': 'Aardappelen',
 'Kruimige aardappelen': 'Aardappelen',
 'Roodschillige aardappelen': 'Aardappelen',
 'Opperdoezer Ronde aardappelen': 'Aardappelen',
 'Gemengd gekruid gehakt': 'Kipgehakt',
 'Kipgehakt met Mexicaanse kruiden': 'Kipgehakt',
 'Half-om-halfgehakt met Italiaanse kruiden': 'Kipgehakt',
 'Kipgehakt met tuinkruiden': 'Kipgehakt',
 'R': 'Ui',
 'o': 'Kipshoarma',
 'd': 'Kipworst',
 'e': 'Kipshoarma',
 ' ': 'Kipworst',
 'u': 'Kipworst',
 'i': 'Kipworst',
 'K': 'Kipshoarma',
 'p': 'Kipworst',
 'f': 'Kipfilet',
 'l': 'Kipshoarma',
 't': 'Kipworst',
 'm': 'Kipshoarma',
 'n': 'Kipshoarma',
 'k': 'Kipshoarma',
 'r': 'Kipshoarma',
 'G': 'Kipworst',
 'w': 'Kipworst',
 's': 'Kipshoarma',
 'a': 'Kipshoarma',
 'h': 'Kipshoarma'}
```

Comment: ``("Rode ui")`` is not a tuple, it's just a string in parens, that's why iterating it will iterate each character, same for the other strings in parens.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you mean for each value in `ingredient_dict` to be a tuple, you need to add a trailing comma inside the parens:

```
ingredient_dict = {
                    'Aardappelen': ('Dunne frieten', 'Half kruimige aardappelen', 'Voorgekookte halve kriel met schil',
                                    'Kruimige aardappelen', 'Roodschillige aardappelen', 'Opperdoezer Ronde aardappelen'),
                    'Kipgehakt': ('Gemengd gekruid gehakt', 'Kipgehakt met Mexicaanse kruiden', 'Half-om-halfgehakt met Italiaanse kruiden',
                                  'Kipgehakt met tuinkruiden'),
                    'Ui': ("Rode ui",),
                    'Kipfilet': ('Kipfilet met tuinkruiden en knoflook',),
                    'Kipworst': ('Gekruide kipworst',),
                    'Kipshoarma': ('Kalkoenshoarma',)
                    }
```

The way you've defined it, the single-element entries are strings, so your iteration is unpacking the string (which is an iterable of characters) instead of a tuple of strings.

If you actually wanted your dictionary to be a mix of tuples and strings (I do not advise this -- consistent data types are much easier to work with), you could adapt your reverse comprehension to that by having it check whether each value `v` is a tuple or not:

```
>>> {x:k for k,v in ingredient_dict.items() for x in (v if isinstance(v, tuple) else (v,))}
{'Dunne frieten': 'Aardappelen', 'Half kruimige aardappelen': 'Aardappelen', 'Voorgekookte halve kriel met schil': 'Aardappelen', 'Kruimige aardappelen': 'Aardappelen', 'Roodschillige aardappelen': 'Aardappelen', 'Opperdoezer Ronde aardappelen': 'Aardappelen', 'Gemengd gekruid gehakt': 'Kipgehakt', 'Kipgehakt met Mexicaanse kruiden': 'Kipgehakt', 'Half-om-halfgehakt met Italiaanse kruiden': 'Kipgehakt', 'Kipgehakt met tuinkruiden': 'Kipgehakt', 'Rode ui': 'Ui', 'Kipfilet met tuinkruiden en knoflook': 'Kipfilet', 'Gekruide kipworst': 'Kipworst', 'Kalkoenshoarma': 'Kipshoarma'}
```

Comment: Thanks a bunch! I overlooked the fact I could just be reading in those values as a list in the dictionary instead of one large tuple. Once I made that edit, it worked!